# T-SQL: LIKE operator, compare string to one value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

Is there a way to compare multiple values in one column to a single value in another column.

Example:

- Column A contains: `[a;b;c;d]`
- Column B contains: `[a]`

At the moment I'm using the `LIKE` operator to achieve this but not result. I tried it with a wildcard `%` but I get no match because of the `;`.

Comment: Seems like you should be fixing your design and not storing delimited data in your database.

Comment: It’s not my database, it’s at a customer site. Just need a quick fix.

Comment: That *is* the "quick" fix. ;)

Comment: String splitting is THE most common question on SO - a little searching will find many examples to fit whatever version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: Please always specify your SQL Server version using an appropriate tag.

Comment: Putting multiple values into a single column is non-relational.  Specifically it is a violation of [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).  Non-relational designs like this inevitably create problems like this.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 3):

As Larnu suggested, the real fix here is to fix the design. You should go back to the owners and remind them that the database is for storing *relational* data; if you're jamming multiple "facts" into a single column, you may as well be using a flat file. The exception is if you are storing a comma-separated list for the application and only the application is responsible for assembling and exploding that set.

Anyway, given that you are probably stuck with this (and let's say `ColumnA` is limited to 128 characters):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.BadDesign
(
  ColumnA nvarchar(128),
  ColumnB nvarchar(max)
);
 
INSERT dbo.BadDesign(ColumnA, ColumnB) VALUES
  (N'[a]', N'[a;b;c;d]'), -- only match
  (N'[p]', N'[q;r;s]'),
  (N'[h]', N'[hi;j;k]');
```

You can see the following solutions demonstrated in turn in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=13b5b44cae17cce961ea4185bc1de5a6):

---

#### Nested Replace

In the old days before (SQL Server 2017), we would perform nested `REPLACE()` calls to get rid of the square brackets and replace each end of the string with delimiters:

```
-- All versions
 
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB
FROM dbo.BadDesign 
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(ColumnB, N'[',N';'),N']', N';')
      LIKE N'%' + REPLACE(REPLACE(ColumnA ,N'[',N';'),N']', N';') + N'%';
```

Gross, but results:

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| [a] | [a;b;c;d] |

We can't use `TRIM()` on versions prior to SQL Server 2017, but I explain below why we don't want to use that function on modern versions anyway.

---

#### OpenJson

In 2016+ we can use `OPENJSON` after a little manipulation to the string. And here I use a `PARSENAME()` trick which is only safe if the `ColumnA` <= 128 characters. I show other workarounds in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7f59805ee6a3ab7a05608d59d3b0d2e2):

```
SELECT b.ColumnA, b.ColumnB 
  FROM dbo.BadDesign AS b
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
    b.ColumnB, N'[', N'["'), N']', N'"]"'), N';', N'","')) AS j
  WHERE j.value = PARSENAME(b.ColumnA, 1);
```

Results:

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| [a] | [a;b;c;d] |

---

#### Translate

In SQL Server 2017, it can be a *little* less gross with `TRANSLATE()`:

```
-- SQL Server 2017+
 
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB 
FROM dbo.BadDesign
WHERE TRANSLATE(ColumnB, N'[]',N';;')
      LIKE N'%' + TRANSLATE(ColumnA, N'[]',N';;') + N'%';
```

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| [a] | [a;b;c;d] |

We don't want to use `TRIM()` here because we don't simply want to *remove* the enclosing square brackets; we want delimiters there so we can always compare A to B regardless of where B is in the string. Without surrounding delimiters replaced or translated, [we could get inaccurate results if the match is at the beginning or end of the multi-value string](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=16ee2e215ef1444f8d518e4a61d90738).

---

#### Split Function

Alternatively, you could create this function on SQL Server 2016+ (or a messier one that doesn't use `STRING_SPLIT()` in earlier versions - as Smor noted, a search will turn up hundreds of those):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitAndClean(@s nvarchar(max))
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  RETURN 
  (
    SELECT value 
      FROM STRING_SPLIT
           (
             -- if 2016:
             REPLACE(REPLACE(@s, N'[',N';'),N']', N';'), 
             -- if 2017+, TRANSLATE() is slightly cleaner:
             /* TRANSLATE(@s, N'[]',N';;'), */
             N';'
           )
      WHERE value > N''
  );
```

Then you can say:

```
SELECT bd.ColumnA, bd.ColumnB
  FROM dbo.BadDesign AS bd
  CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitAndClean(bd.ColumnA) AS a
  CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitAndClean(bd.ColumnB) AS b
  WHERE a.value = b.value;
```

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| [a] | [a;b;c;d] |

---

#### But in the end...

...these are all gross "solutions" masking bad design, and you should really have them reconsider how they're using the database.

I know that many shops can't just switch to [passing sets between the app and the database using TVPs](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql), because several client providers and ORMs haven't quite had more than a decade to catch that train. If you can't use TVPs or can't change the app, you should at least consider intercepting the comma-separated list passed by the app and break it apart using `SPLIT_STRING()` or the like. Then you can store the values relationally and let the database do what the database was designed to do, without being handcuffed by app limitations.

Comment: Erm `TRIM('[]' FROM @s)` maybe, instead of `REPLACE(REPLACE(`?

Comment: @Charlieface updated to address your "Erm" - again we can't use `TRIM()` in place of nested `REPLACE()` on older versions, because `TRIM()` doesn't exist. And on 2017+ `TRANSLATE()` makes more sense here.

Answer (score 0):

If there will be always only one value in col_b like in your example, you can user nested replace function to remove [ and ] and then use "like" for search

```
select *
  from test_data
 where col_a like '%' + replace(replace(col_b, '[', ''), ']', '') + '%';
```

But

if there could be more than value in col_b and it could be in any order (e.g. "[a;c]" or "[d;a]") you'll find answer among already answered questions or you may google for "string_split()" function on msdn. The latter has great examples section that will definitely help you out

Comment: I think you've got the columns swapped, but you also need to account for the delimiters. Otherwise `[ab;c]` will match `LIKE '%a%'`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand you're right, I did not think of that case. Thanks!